# Complex nested nested if/else in the view causing performance issues

Tags: knockout.js

I've got nested if/else bindings in the view within a foreach that takes about a second to process. It blocks the render while it creates the Dom. I'm planning on doing the if/else conditions in JavaScript and shipping the whole dom element to the view pre-prepared to speed things. However I'm new to knockout so not sure if this is a valid approach or if there are better alternatives. The code below is the offending code with most of the data stripped out to display the structure. Within the individual a, li etc are individual bindings onto the DOM element.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: categories; ">
<!-- ko if: $data.childCategories -->

<!-- ko ifnot: $data.id == 'example' -->

<!-- ko if: $data.id == 'another-example' -->

<li data-bind="attr: {'data-children': childCategories}">
    <!-- ko if: $data.id.indexOf('link-') < 0 -->
        <!-- ko if: $data.childCategories -->
            <a>

            </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: $data.childCategories -->
            <a>

            </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: $data.id.indexOf('link-') >= 0 -->
        <!-- ko if: $data.longDescription.indexOf('http') >= 0 -->
            <!-- ko if: $data.childCategories -->
                <a></a>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: $data.childCategories -->
                <a></a>
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: $data.longDescription.indexOf('http') >= 0  -->
            <!-- ko if: $data.childCategories -->
                <a></a>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: $data.childCategories -->
                <a></a>
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->


    <ul data-bind="foreach: childCategories ">
        <li>
            <!-- ko if: $data.id.indexOf('link-') < 0 -->
                <a></a>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <!-- ko if: $data.id.indexOf('link-') >= 0 -->
                <!-- ko if: $data.longDescription.indexOf('http') >= 0 -->
                    <!-- ko if: $data.childCategories -->
                        <a></a>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko ifnot: $data.childCategories -->
                        <a></a>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: $data.longDescription.indexOf('http') >= 0  -->
                    <!-- ko if: $data.childCategories -->
                        <a></a>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko ifnot: $data.childCategories -->
                        <a></a>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->


            <!-- ko if: $data.childCategories -->
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <!-- ko if: $data.id.indexOf('link-') < 0 -->
                                <a></a>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if: $data.id.indexOf('link-') >= 0 -->
                                <!-- ko if: $data.longDescription.indexOf('http') >= 0 -->
                                    <a></a>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- ko ifnot: $data.longDescription.indexOf('http') >= 0  -->
                                    <a></a>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </div>
                        <ul data-bind="foreach: $data.childCategories">
                            <li></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko ifnot: $data.id == 'another-example' -->
<li data-bind="attr: {'data-children': childCategories}">
        <!-- ko if: $data.id.indexOf('link-') < 0 -->
            <!-- ko if: $data.childCategories -->
                <a>

                </a>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: $data.childCategories -->
                <a>

                </a>
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: $data.id.indexOf('link-') >= 0 -->
            <!-- ko if: $data.longDescription.indexOf('http') >= 0 -->
                <!-- ko if: $data.childCategories -->
                    <a></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: $data.childCategories -->
                    <a></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: $data.longDescription.indexOf('http') >= 0  -->
                <!-- ko if: $data.childCategories -->
                    <a></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: $data.childCategories -->
                    <a></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->




            <!-- ko if: $data.childCategories -->
            <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <!-- ko if: $data.id.indexOf('link-') < 0 -->
                                <a></a>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if: $data.id.indexOf('link-') >= 0 -->
                                <!-- ko if: $data.longDescription.indexOf('http') >= 0 -->
                                    <a></a>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- ko ifnot: $data.longDescription.indexOf('http') >= 0  -->
                                    <a></a>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </div>
                        <ul data-bind="foreach: $data.childCategories">
                            <li></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- /ko -->









    </li>
<!-- /ko -->


<!-- /ko -->




<!-- /ko -->


<!-- ko ifnot: $data.childCategories -->

    <!-- ko if: $data.id.indexOf('link-') < 0 -->
        <li>
            <a>
            </a>
        </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: $data.id.indexOf('link-') >= 0 -->
        <li></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: What does your view currently look like? There's probably a better way, but we'll need to see what you have first.

Comment: I won't be able to post the code but I can go into more detail around how it's constructed. We retrieve a JSON object that contains arrays of other objects which in turn have more nested arrays a few layers deep. This defines the structure for a product catalogues categories. The view is constructed now has a foreach on the top level objects and multiple levels of if/else and data bindings. The render blocks and you can see multiple layouts/paints happening.

Comment: If that doesn't help, I could look at posting a stripped down version of it here to help illustrate the issue.

Comment: I've added a stripped down version of what the structure looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a deferred update extension on your observableArray()? this way it all happens async, mostly before any ui (re)draws

```
this.data = ko.observableArray().extend({ deferred: true });
```

see for more info: https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/deferred-updates.html

Alternatively there's another little trick when you're preparing your data, if you're already working on the observableArray() and iterating through while updating bound child-observables and whatnot, having a lot of notifcations going back and forth, it's sometimes easier to work with a simple js-object, then pushing all changes at once back into back the observable like so

```
var items = ko.observableArray();
//do something with the items here
items.push.apply(items, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Doing it this way might help you setting up the if-then-else checks as a bool on each of your items in the array, elevating the checks whilst the ui render is sorting it out and moving into the code.. just a suggestion.
Either way knockout should be able to handle -a lot of- if then else conditionals without viewing too much issues in the ui, most of the time you can speed things up by rethinking how the observables are being (ab)used.

I've worked on controls that held 20k+ items coming from an api and into an observableArray, filtering out a subset on conditions and displaying them in a matter of miliseconds onto the web page with templates and if-then conditions all around. (ye I know it's a bit much for proper use but that's not the point)

Comment: Thanks I tried the deferred yesterday and there wasn't a measurable improvement for me. I'll give the  alternative method you suggested a try.

Comment: if it doesn't help you should really try to put a very basic jsfiddle of what you're trying to achieve, there might be something else entirely that we can't possible know without viewing what you're actually doing.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll put something together this afternoon.

Comment: I've added a stripped down version of what the structure looks like.

Comment: I'm sorry but I personally would like a working jsfiddle that shows the 1second delay, I'm not going to try to completely gather the viewmodel from that view and insert a list of data in there, that's kinda your move :) also at first glance I see a lot of returning code, have you considered a template that you might/not use recursively? it'll shorten this view a lot

Comment: That's fully understandable. I'll have a look at the template.